# Edit the value of an <input> element by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to fill an  element with data using jQuery.

Unfortunately, the element stays blank. Until now, i used a workaround and used a textarea instead of input (which is working for some reason).

I did not only try

```
$('#input').val("Text") ;
```

but also

```
$('#input').text("text") ;
$('#input').attr("value", "Text") ;
```

I do not understand this behaviour, outside of my project it works just fine.
Maybe an overlook over the [complete code](http://pastebin.com/D59MxffL) could help. (Excuse the codemess)

Also i've got a small sidequestion:
I'm using `async: false` to make the whole thing work, if i remove it, nothing will be shown. But as i know that this is deprectaed, what alternatives do i have?

Thank you very much.

Comment: So after all i fixed the problem by replacing `slideDown` with `fadeIn`. This is correctly shown in Chrome as well as in FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hell...
i found it. It's not like the value isn't be inserted, it's just not visible O_o

MY Chrome does not show the word "test" inside the input when it is hidden by jQuery before.

With FF, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

there is no `element` with ID of `input` in your HTML, i think you want to change the value of `input elements`, change this:

```
$('#input').val("Text") ; // this is an ID selector
```

to

```
$('input').val("Text") ;
```

Comment: There are multiple input elements.

Answer (score 0):

`#input` searches for an element with id input. I did not see any on the source code.

As you want to change text of a single input field , give it an unique id. Like `id='sampleText'` then change its value like ,

`$("#sampleText").val("Your text");`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some errors please check.

```
<form id="editForm" method="POST" action="updatedata.php">
                **<input type="text" id="editHeading" name="editHeading" /></textarea><br>**
                <textarea id="editAuthor" name="editAuthor" /></textarea><br>
                <textarea id="editTag" name="editTag" type="text" /></textarea><br>
                <textarea id="editarea" name="editarea"></textarea><br>
                <input id="id" name="id">
                <input id="submitEditForm" name="submitEditForm" type="submit" /><br>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI some general concepts

```
$('input').val('foo'); //updates with value foo for all input elements
$('#input').val('foo'); //updates with value foo an input element with id #input

$('span#a').val('foo'); //wont work ,here we have to use .html 
$('span#a').html('foo'); //<span>foo</span>
```

Comment: Should have said that the "input" id is only pseudo and for showcases